# MS Access changing event results in error (VBA)

Tags: ms-access

I am encountering an error in Access 2013. I am trying to change `Private Sub Form_Current()` to `Private Sub Form_Open()`.

However, doing so results in the following error:

```
This error occurs when an event has failed to run because the location of the 
logic for the event cannot be evaluated. For example, if the OnOpen property of 
a form is set to =[Field], this error occurs because a macro or event name is 
expected to run when the event occurs.
```

Inside the event I set various checkboxes and such to be `Null` or `False`

```
Me![Combo1] = Null
Me![Combo2] = Null
Me![CB1] = False
. . .
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to change Private Sub Form_Current() to Private Sub Form_Open()

Don't do that. Create the procedure via the "Event" tab of the properties window, and then move the code from one to the other.

The subs have different signatures:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

End Sub
```

vs

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, face palm. Thanks for that!